# Tensorflow Coding Optimization: How Do I implement this kind code more efficiently?

Tags: tensorflow

I have an outer loop training my model and update my x; however, each iteration in outer loop; it requires to train another model and to train the inner model; it requires the current outer iteration's value x

The general frame is as follows

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # do some initial computation
        x = ......

        for i in (range(iters)):
            loss = func(x) # compute the loss function
            train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            for j in (range(train_steps)):
                per_loss = session.run([loss])
                sess.run([train_op])

             # update x
             x = .....
```

This implementation is very slow; so I decide to use placeholder

```
x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,....)
loss = func(x_placholder)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # do some initial computation
    x = ......

    for i in (range(iters)):
       sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for j in (range(train_steps)):
            per_loss = session.run([train_op, loss],feed_dict={x_placeholder:x})

         # update x
         x = .....
```

However, this gives me error as follows

```
raise ValueError("No variables to optimize.")
ValueError: No variables to optimize.
```

when run the line `train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)`

So I'm not sure how to correctly implement this in very efficient way.Any idea

Thanks

Comment: I know some of these words

Comment: @BDillan; I'm sorry?

Comment: I know a guy named Adam, besides that I can't follow the code

Comment: What does, `tf.trainable_variables()` print? Also, is the other model getting trained loaded in the same session or some other session?

Comment: @thelogicalkoan it will be the parameters of the inner model. x update is done by me manually

Comment: In which graph is your model getting loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,....)
loss = func(x_placholder)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
        # do some initial computation
        x = ......

        for i in (range(iters)):
           sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            for j in (range(train_steps)):
                per_loss = session.run([train_op, loss],feed_dict={x_placeholder:x})

             # update x
             x = .....
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; so when one use placeholder; the train.opt no longer works. It raises error `ValueError: No variables to optimize.`

Comment: Can you also post describe what operations you are doing on the placeholder?

Comment: I have an outer loop training my model and update my x; however, each iteration in outer loop; it requires to train another model and to train the inner model; it requires the current outer iteration's value x